# Efficient way of getting all possible paths + special detail

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I'm facing a path finding problem in which I have to find every possible path from one point to another. It would be very easy if it was just that - I'd use a breadth-first algorithm, just like the one explained [here](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs.html).

The problem is that, in this case, every edge has a **maximum number of times that can be used**. Let's see it with an example:

[image: Example graph]

In this case, I can go 15 times from A to D. The first 10 times, the path would be A -> B -> C -> D. The remaining 5 times, the path would be A -> C -> D.

So far I've been able to implement a solution (using python) but it's quite slow for medium problems (about 30 nodes). I have an unweighted graph (as I don't mind the length of the path) with the possible connections between the different nodes, and separately I have a matrix with the *usage limit* of each edge.

So, inside a loop:

- I find a single possible path.
- I update the matrix of usages. The usage of that path would be the minimum of the usages of the edges (as in, you can use a path as many times as the part of the path with the minimum limit).
- For each edge whose usage reaches 0, it means it can no longer be used, so I delete it from the graph.
- Loop until all paths are found.

As I said, this works, but it's quite slow. I've been able to increase the overall performance by sorting the list of edges for each node based on the number of times it can use, but it's still slow.

Any clues?

Comment: I am *really* itching to say try Wikipedia. This seems like such a good problem, so I think there is an article on it (goes to check).

Comment: When you find a path, you're subtracting the lowest edge from each edge on that path, right ?

Comment: Right cnicutar, I'm gonna edit it to clarify that point.

Comment: There's a contradiction in the problem as you formulate it: when pass limit for at least one (!) edge is lower than the count of paths passing through it, you no more are searching **all** paths. Instead, you then search **some** paths, and the criteria on which paths to find are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could present your problem as a maximum flow problem. Instead of saying  that you can travel A to B 10 times, you might say A to B may accomodate a flow of 10 m^3/s. And your graph is a network of pipes that may accomodate a total flow of 15m^3/s from A to D. So you may start with a look at the algorithms listed [here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).

There are some points that are unclear to me in your problem. Depending on your answer, it might not qualify as a flow problem.

1. If you increase the A to C capacity to 6, the maximum flow from A to D is still 15, but there are several ways to realise that (either 6 directly to C and 9 through B or 5 and 10). Are you satisfied with any of these answers or do you want them all ? In the same spirit, if there were another path from A to C (say through a node E) would you accept it to be ignored in the results, as C to D is saturated anyway.
2. If there were a cycle in a graph (say an edge from C back to B) would you count going through this cycle never, once, twice or more as different solutions.

Comment: Thanks for giving me that keyword, "maximum flow". I'll look for it. Regarding your questions:
1. Yep, I'm satisfied as long as I know the max flow is 15, no matter the paths.
2. Cicles are supposed to be ignored, you can visit each node just once per path.

Comment: So it is a indeed a maximum flow problem, and there are textbook algorithms to do that. Much easier than having to invent one.

Comment: Yeah! Nice, Edmonds-Karp algorithm did the work REALLY fast! Thanks